# Convert CSV file to Siddhi event

Tags: csv, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I want to convert a CSV file to a set of Siddhi events using WSO2 Stream Processor, in order to use that CSV file to train a kmeansIncremental model.

I tried to source that csv file using 'file' as the source type and 'csv' as the map type but, I could not do that.

```
@source(type='file',file.uri='file:///home/Documents/Project%20Documents/logs/access.csv', @map(type='csv', header.present='true', event-grouping-enabled='true'))
```

define stream ProductionStream(latitude double, longitude double, frequency int, day int, timegap double, res_ratio double, client_id string);

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting. 
Share the complete stacktrace along with the complete Siddhi App.

Please refer the CSV mapping with File source/sink samples available in [Product SP](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/tree/master/modules/samples/artifacts/CSVMappingWithFile) as reference.